# Is $\limsup f(x) \le \liminf g(x)$ if $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

I was wondering if the following is true. $\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) \le \liminf_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ if $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x$.

One more constrain we can impose is that $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are monotone and non-negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious counter-example to the original Question is to take $f(x)=g(x)$, so the latter inequality is always satisfied.  Now  take $f(x)$ to exhibit some oscillation, e.g. $f(x) = \cos x$, whence:

$$ \lim \sup_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 1 \gt -1 = \lim \inf_{x\to \infty} f(x) $$

If you impose the additional constraint that these are monontone and non-negative functions, then $\lim \sup_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim \inf_{x\to \infty} g(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$.  Then $f(x) \le g(x)$ does imply that (on the extended real line) $\lim \sup_{x\to \infty} f(x) \le \lim \inf_{x\to \infty} g(x)$ because we are simply talking about their limits.

Comment: thanks. But $f(x)=cos(x)$ is not monotone and non-negative. I think, I was making edits when you responded.

Comment: Okay, but with your revised constraint there is no distinction between `lim sup` and `lim inf`; both agree with the monotone limit (even if this happens to be $+\infty$).

Comment: Yes. you are right. What if I change it from monotone to decreasing? Would the result change.

Comment: If decreasing (still monotone) and non-negative (bounded below by zero), the result only changes inasmuch as the limits are finite.  The same would be true more generally if you know monotone and bounded above.

Answer (score 3):

Define $f(n)=1$ if $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, otherwise $0$. Let $g=f$; then $\lim\sup f(x) = 1$ and $\lim\inf g(x) = 0$

If $f\leq g $ is monotone, then $\lim\inf f(x)=\lim\sup f(x) \leq \lim\inf g(x)=\lim\sup g(x)$

Comment: I think I meant decreasing instead of monotone. Would thing change than?

Comment: I think @hardmath already gives you the answer :)